# activate script when element has class then reset it when there is no class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list i want it to convert the value to there initials only when the list have a class. reset it again to there original value when the list have no class.

HTML:

```
   <ul class="mm-listview">
    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home" title="Home"></i> Home</a>
     <ul>
      <li class="sample"><a href="admin-start-page.html">Admin Delta Charlie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">Rima Tango</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-user" title="Charlie Papa"></i> Content Edition</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#/">Tango Romeo Delta</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">India Uniform Echo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">Zulu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">Mama Echo</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<button class="toggle-class" style="position: absolute;background-color: red;z-index: 9999;margin-top: 200px;">Toggle Class</button>
```

SCRIPT:

```
  $(function () {

   function changeUL() {
          if($('.mm-listview .mm-listview').hasClass('active-menu')) {
              $('.mm-listview .mm-listview').data('initial ', $('.mm-listview .mm-listview').html());
              $(".mm-listview .mm-listview li a").html(function (i, v) {
                  return v.trim().split(" ").map(function (obj) {
                      return obj.substr(0, 1);
                  }).join("");
              });
          } else {
              if($('.mm-listview .mm-listview').data('initial ').length > 0) {
                  $('.mm-listview .mm-listview').empty();
                  $('.mm-listview .mm-listview li a').append($('.mm-listview .mm-listview').data('initial '));
              }
          }
      }
      $('button').on('click', function() {
          $('.mm-listview .mm-listview').toggleClass('active-menu');
          changeUL();
      });

   });
```

OUTPUT WITH CLASS:

```
<ul class="mm-listview">
                <li class="mm-vertical"><a class="mm-next" href="#mm-1" data-target="#mm-1"></a><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home" title="Home"></i> Home</a>
                    <div class="mm-panel mm-vertical" id="mm-1"><ul class="mm-listview mm-vertical active-menu">
                        <li class="sample"><a href="admin-start-page.html">ADC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/">RT</a></li>
                    </ul></div>
                </li>
                <li class="mm-vertical"><a class="mm-next" href="#mm-2" data-target="#mm-2"></a><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-user" title="Content Edition"></i> Content Editor</a>
                    <div class="mm-panel mm-vertical" id="mm-2"><ul class="mm-listview mm-vertical active-menu">
                        <li><a href="#/">TRD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/">IUE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/">Z</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/">ME</a></li>
                    </ul></div>
                </li>
</UL>
```

After that the ul will only get the value of the first ul not getting back to the original lists.

```
<ul class="mm-listview">
    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home" title="Home"></i> Home</a>
     <ul>
      <li class="sample"><a href="admin-start-page.html">Admin Delta Charlie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">Rima Tango</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-user" title="Charlie Papa"></i> Content Edition</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#/">Admin Delta Charlie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">Rima Tango</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I should be able to toggle back to the original value to the Initial only values  just exactly on the `HTML`

Comment: Do you have a problem with this code?

Comment: Once the class has been remove the value doesn't come back to the original.

Comment: How do you change the class? Add the code please.

Comment: please check the edited one.

Comment: @MichaelPon - You need a function which stores the original value before you reduce them down to the initials. So perhaps store the values in `localstorage`, a global javascript object or in the backend on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the initial values of the list elements using jQuery's `data()`method.

[**jQuery.data()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or return the value that was set.

```js
$(function () {

    function changeUL() {
        if($('ul').hasClass('active')) {
            $('ul').data('initial', $('ul').html());
            $("li").html(function (i, v) {
                return v.trim().split(" ").map(function (obj) {
                    return obj.substr(0, 1);
                }).join("");
            });
        } else {
            if($('ul').data('initial').length > 0) {
                $('ul').empty();
                $('ul').append($('ul').data('initial'));
            }
        }
    }
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('ul').toggleClass('active');
        changeUL();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Alpha Beta</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
</ul>

<button class="toggle-class">Toggle Class</button>
```

**-- Edit --**

Example with nested unordered list elements.

```js
$(function () {

  function changeUL() {
    if($('ul').hasClass('active')) {
      $('ul').data('initial', $('ul').html());
      $('ul').not('.mm-listview').each(function(){
        $(this).find('a').html(function (i, v) {
          if($(v).parent().children().length < 1) {
            return v.trim().split(" ").map(function (obj) {
              return obj.substr(0, 1);
            }).join("");
          }
        });
      })
    } else {
      if($('ul').data('initial').length > 0) {
        $('ul').empty();
        $('ul').append($('ul').data('initial'));
        $('ul').each(function(){
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
      }
    }
  }
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('ul').each(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');

    })
    changeUL();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mm-listview">
  <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home" title="Home"></i> Home</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="sample"><a href="admin-start-page.html">Admin Delta Charlie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">Rima Tango</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-user" title="Charlie Papa"></i> Content Edition</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/">Tango Romeo Delta</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">India Uniform Echo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">Zulu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">Mama Echo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<button class="toggle-class">Toggle Class</button>
```

Comment: can you do this with 2nd level ul li and 3rd level? im having problem loading the initial value it converts the value of the convert one

Comment: @MichaelPon - made an edit to the answer, added an example with 2nd and 3rd level unordered lists. You just have to remove the `active` class on the nested list elements after appending them back into the DOM.

Comment: I'm having problem making the value get back to the original. All of my 2nd level copies the first set of ul. can you make all of the first level have a 2nd level and 3rd level? updated the question.

Comment: @MichaelPon - Sorry, my last edit was not correct. I did not nest the `ul`'s correctly. Made a change. Is this what you mean, or am i misunderstanding something here?

Comment: can you check my codes. I updated it with the ones inheriting the values of the first ul

Comment: @MichaelPon - Now i got what you mean. Made an update with your example code.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help

```js
$(function () {
  $("li").html(function (i, v) {
      $('li:eq('+i+')').attr('before', v.trim());
    return v.trim().split(" ").map(function (obj) {
      return obj.substr(0, 1);
    }).join("");
  });
});

/* TOGGLE FOR ADDINGG CLASS */
   $(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
     $("ul li").toggleClass("active");
        if(!$("ul li:first").hasClass('active')) {
         $("li").html(function (i, v) {
                  return $('li:eq('+i+')').attr('before');
              });
        } else {
         $("li").html(function (i, v) {
                return v.trim().split(" ").map(function (obj) {
                    return obj.substr(0, 1);
                }).join("");
              });
        }
    });

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">Alpha Beta</li>
  <li class="active">Beta</li>
  <li class="active">Charlie</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="btn" ">Toggle Active</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better put the old values in a `data-attribute` and get them from there the second time.

```
function onActive() {
  $("li").html(function (i, v) {
    $(this).data('old_value',v);
    return v.trim().split(" ").map(function (obj) {
      return obj.substr(0, 1);
    }).join("");
  });
}
```

And the second time:

```
function onInActive() {
  $("li").html(function (i, v) {
    $(this).html($(this).data('old_value'));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After the html is rendered, assign the ul's html to a variable (`originalHtml` in my code), if it's active run the logic to abbreviate the text, if not use the original:

```js
$(function () {

    var $ul = $('ul');
    var originalHtml = $('ul').html();

    function toggleData() {
        if($ul.hasClass('active')) {
            $ul.find("li").html(function (i, v) {
                return v.trim().split(" ").map(function (obj) {
                    return obj.substr(0, 1);
                }).join("");
            });

            return;
        }

        $ul.html(originalHtml);
    }
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $ul.toggleClass('active');
        toggleData();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Alpha Beta</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
</ul>

<button class="toggle-class">Toggle Class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally call a function to do the changing of text on button click as suggested by @DavidDomain & @Ori Drori but maybe you are looking for something other than that.

In your case you need the changes when the class active is added. So we will have an external function which will track any change in the class and make the modifications.

```js
/* TOGGLE FOR ADDINGG CLASS */
$(function(){
   $('ul li').each(function(){
     $(this).data('name',$(this).html()); 
   });
             
   $("#btn").click(function(){
     $("ul li").toggleClass("active");
   });
        
});


  var rex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
  var actualtext = '';
  var t = setInterval(function () {
  $("ul li").each(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        if($(this).data('name') == $(this).html()){
           $(this).html(function (i, v) {
               actualtext = v.replace(rex,"").trim()
               intials = actualtext.split(" ").map(function (obj) {
                 return obj.substr(0, 1);
               }).join("");
               return v.replace(actualtext,intials)
           });
        }
     }else{
        $(this).html($(this).data('name'));
     }   
   });
         
    },100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Alpha Beta</a></li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
</ul>

<button id="btn">click</btn>
```

the benifit of using this is that if you set `active` class on the elemts form anywhere else, you don ot need to worry about calling a seperate function to make the UL changes.

Comment: what if i have an anchor on my li like this one. <li data-name='Charlie'><a href="#">Charlie</a></li> the value will change but it will not be an anchor.

Comment: then you can add the same anchor tag to the `data-name` atttibutes. the code will work. something like this  : 
`<li data-name='<a href="#">Charlie</a>'><a href="#">Charlie</a></li> `

Comment: I have updated the answer to modify it according to your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript you can do like this

```
    function toggle() {
        var a = document.querySelector('ul');
        if (!a.classList.contains('active')) {
            for (var i = 0; i < a.children.length; i++) {
                var s = a.children[i].innerHTML.split(' '),
                    c;
                c = s.map(function(item) {
                    return item.substr(0, 1);
                });
                a.children[i].innerHTML = c.join("");
            }
            a.classList.add('active');
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < a.children.length; i++) {
                a.children[i].innerHTML = a.children[i]['dataset']['val'];
            }
            a.classList.remove('active');
        }
    } 

<ul>
  <li data-val = "Alpha Beta">Alpha Beta</li> 
  <li data-val = "Beta">Beta</li> 
  <li data-val = "Charlie">Charlie</li> 
</ul> 
<button onclick = "toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use a css based approach

```
li{
    display: none;
}

li.active{
    display: block!important;
}

<ul>
  <li class="">Alpha Beta</li><li class="active">AB</li>
  <li class="">Beta</li><li class="active">B</li>
  <li class="">Charlie</li><li class="active">C</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="btn" ">Sample</a>
```

and then

```
$(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
     $("ul li").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```